# Query closest points on triangles with CGAL python bindings

Tags: python, geometry, cgal

This [CGAL python binding example](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal-swig-bindings/blob/master/examples/python/AABB_triangle_3_example.py) is great to show how to get the closest point on a triangle soup using an AABB tree. Unfortunately it only returns the single closest point on the closest triangle.

I'm looking for a function where i can feed a query point(s), an array of triangles, and then get a closest point per triangles as a return.

The only way i found to do this is by iterating over the triangles one at a time, make an AABB_tree_Triangle_3_soup for each, and query... This feels very inefficient, especially since the [example](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal-swig-bindings/blob/master/examples/python/AABB_triangle_3_example.py) clearly can deal with the array of triangles at once.

To help illustrate, here's an image of what i'm looking for:

[image]

The red dot is the query point, each blue dot are the triangle's vertices, the green dots are the closest points with each line as it's projection.

Here's the code i came up with so far. The code works, but isn't very pretty.

```
# Imports
import time
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree

from CGAL.CGAL_Kernel import Point_3
from CGAL.CGAL_Kernel import Triangle_3
from CGAL.CGAL_AABB_tree import AABB_tree_Triangle_3_soup

# Setup the source data
# ---------------------

# Create large numpy array of triangles
N_TRIANGLES = 100000 #100K triangles
np_triangles = np.random.random_sample((N_TRIANGLES,3,3,)) # lets make a random array for this example

# Create a random query point
np_query = np.random.random_sample((3,)) * 100 # lets use a random point for this example

# Convert the data so we can use CGAL
cgal_triangles = []
for p in np_triangles:
    a = Point_3(p[0][0],p[0][1],p[0][2])
    b = Point_3(p[1][0],p[1][1],p[1][2])
    c = Point_3(p[2][0],p[2][1],p[2][2])
    cgal_triangles.append(Triangle_3(a,b,c))

cgal_query = Point_3(np_query[0],np_query[1],np_query[2])



# Test begins!
# ------------

# If all i care for is to find THE closest point on all the given triangles to the query point, it's easy:
def simple_closest():
    tree = AABB_tree_Triangle_3_soup(cgal_triangles)
    cp = tree.closest_point(cgal_query)
    return np.array([cp.x(),cp.y(),cp.z()])

simple_closest_result = simple_closest()


# Unfortunately, what i want is a return value for all given triangles, which i could sort in the future for N closest if need be
# The only way i found to do this is to make an AABB tree per triangle, which sounds silly, and is the focus of my question
def all_closest():
    cp = []
    for t in cgal_triangles:
        tree = AABB_tree_Triangle_3_soup([t])
        p = tree.closest_point(cgal_query)
        cp.append([p.x(),p.y(),p.z()])

    return np.array(cp)

all_closest_result = all_closest()


# From here, if i wish to sort the results to get all the points from closest to furthest, i can do that
N = 8  # Lets say i want the 8 closest triangles to the query point
n = max(min(N, N_TRIANGLES), 1) # clamp n <= tri count


def n_closest():
    kdTree = cKDTree(all_closest_result)
    q = kdTree.query(np_query,k=n)
    return all_closest_result[q[1]], q[0], q[1]

n_closest_result = n_closest()


print ''
print 'Does the closest item match: %s'%np.allclose(n_closest_result[0][0],simple_closest_result)
print 'Closest Simple:\n%s'%simple_closest_result
print '%s closest'%n
print n_closest_result[0]
```

This example shows how i had to iterate over the triangles one at a time. Create an AABB_tree_Triangle_3_soup for each single triangles, and then query. This sounds highly inefficient. Especially when dealing with many many queries, like 100k queries of a list of a million triangles.

So, what i'm looking for is a better way than my iteration method. Hopefully a single command... like:

tree = AABB_tree_Triangle_3_soup(triangles)
   tree.all_points(query) # returns unsorted closest points
   tree.all_closest(query,n=56) # returns the 56 closest points

Answer (score 0):

You need to use another package ([Spatial searching](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Spatial_searching/index.html)). I notice the only example using this package in the bindings was in java. I added one in [python](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal-swig-bindings/blob/master/examples/python/test_sp.py).

Comment: my apologies for misleading you with how i formulated my question. The way i previously formulated my question sounded like i was trying to find N nearest points to a point in CGAL. I'm looking for N closest points on triangles. The example i mentionned gives me THE nearest point, which is useful, but it would be best if CGAL could give me the nearest points on N triangles to a query point, and then i could use your Spacial searching example (or scipy's cKDTree) to sort for the N nearest one.

Comment: I'm not sure it makes sense. The whole neighborhood of the closest point in the triangle will contain all the closest points.

Comment: I added a lot of details with example code. Please see the very last paragraph for hopefully even more clarity :) and thanks for all your help!!!